# iOS 5 banner push notification disappear, user tap on app icon to start the app

Tags: ios5, push-notification, banner

With iOS 5, push notifications can appear as banner and disappear after a few seconds.
I understand that didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called when user taps on the banner.

My question is, if the banner has disappeared and my user sees that there is a badge number on the app, they will tap on the app icon to start the app. Now if the app is running in the background, how do I check that the app is brought to foreground and there has been a notification, and do the necessary?

The purpose of my notification is basically to inform user there has been an update to the app content and encourage them to run the app to get the latest contents. My app only checks for latest contents at launch time and doesn't check for updates periodically.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I'll pop what I've found in here anyway.

There are two methods you need to implement in your app delegate to check if your app was either launched from the remote notification (From when the app is not running on your device), or received the remote notification while running (in the background or foreground).

First is a method that is already in your App Delegate:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

To check if this was launched from a remote notification, have some code similar to this:

```
// Check to see if launched from notification
if (launchOptions != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

The other method you will need to implement is specifically for the case that your application for when your application is running:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
}
```

How you handle the notification from there is up to you, but that's how your app knows about it!

In this second method, you can check the UIApplicationState of the passed application to find out if you were in the foreground or background.